# 要素を2乗するプログラム

Tags: c

授業の課題で出題された問題です。
整数配列dataに対し、要素番号iの2乗をdata[i]に格納する手続きsqarrayを作成する問題で、自分は以下のようにプログラムしました。

```
/*
ex1401.c
*/

#include <stdio.h>

void sqarray(int data[], int size)
{
  int i;
for (i=0;i<size;i=i+1) {
printf("%d ",&data[i]);
}
}

void printIntArray(int a[], int size)
{
  int i;
for (i=0;i<size;i=i+1) {
printf("%d ",a[i]);
}
printf("\n");
}


int main(void)
{
  int data[100], n;

  printf("n=? ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  sqarray(data, n);
  printIntArray(data, n);


return 0;
}
```

しかし、以下のようなエラーを表示されました。

```
ex1401.c: In function ‘sqarray’:
ex1401.c:11:10: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
 printf("%d ",&data[i]);
         ~^   ~~~~~~~~
         %ls
```

上記の指摘では、"%d"が"%ls"のようになるということだと思い、直してみたのですが、またエラーがでました。
自分のプログラムはどのようなところがおかしいのでしょうか。

Comment: アドバイス頂いたようにdata[i]に直しました。エラーは出なくなったのですが、以下のようにｎ＝?の状態から横に数字を入れると、端末が停止してしまいました。　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　`$ cc ex1401.c` 　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　`$ ./a.out`
　　`n=? 10`

Comment: その部分は、新しい質問として投稿してみてください。また、このコメントはサイトの誰にも通知がいっていないので、次からは回答に対してコメントいただけるとありがたいです。そうすると回答の投稿者に通知が飛びます :)

Answer (score 2):

直すべきは `&data[i]` の方です。

> warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’

この警告は、引数には `int` 型の値を期待していたのに、実際には `int *` 型の値が渡されたということを注意するものです。ここでは（おそらくデバッグ用に？）配列 `data` の `i` 番目の要素を表示したいのでしょうから、`printf` に渡すべきは `&data[i]` ではなく `data[i]` です。`&data[i]` だと `data[i]` のアドレスを渡すことになってしまいます。